He is ill/well/highly reputed of

He is ill reputed of.

Do we need 'of' here? That is, "He is ill reputed." sounds or reads natural or naturally.
If 'of' is okay here, where does this 'of' come from?
https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/010f6070a0f446199c407c9ad582156a


[![enter image description here][3]][3]
edit: I think- They highly repute of A (as B) : A is higly reputed of (by them) (as B)
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/M6G6YHMp.png

Where does the "of" come from? Did you find this somewhere? If so, please tell about the source. Some other similar patterns, like "well spoken of" include "of," but "repute" doesn't.

I added the source. Still, I wonder why ther is 'of'.

Thanks; I added another screenshot of the actual usage. Yeah; I guess sometimes you just find questionable examples in some dictionaries.

Those dictionary images are very hard to deal with. Just copy the information even if you have to retype it.

Not sure what this dictionary is, the best-regarded ones seem to be Naver or Collins. Lots of free dictionary apps are made by someone who's found a word list online and stuck it in a basic app framework without checking it. Often they'll do multiple languages in a mechanical way.

Your sentence doesn't work - we don't use the verb repute in that way. Say He has a bad reputation or, more formally, He is a man of ill repute.
Repute as a verb is used in sentences like He is reputed to be a bad character (he is generally believed to be).

It might be worth mentioning, the question title mentions "well" and "highly." These might take this pattern, but to the OP's core question, don't need "of".

'repute' is rarely in use these days. 'He has a good/bad/great reputation' is much more natural.

@LeLetter - Agreed. It's old-fashioned as well as formal.

The main surviving use of the word in American English is the somewhat archaic phrase "house of ill repute" meaning a brothel. That appears to be the form the quoted author was trying, and failing, to adapt. "He is reputed to be" is another archaic but surviving usage of the word, with the connotation that the claim is believable but not supported by evidence.

As I edited, I think 'They higly repute of A (as B)' becomes passive voice: A(He) is highly reputed of (as B) (by them)

There is no such expression as to highly repute of (someone). As I said, the verb repute is only used in the passive - be reputed to be (something) meaning that people believe something about that person.

This dictionary example has several problems.

It's not even idiomatic to say "he is ill reputed," using even without the "of." A more common pattern would be "he is of ill repute."
The dictionary combines "ill," "well," and "highly," implying, they can be used in parallel ways. Although the proposed construction, using the preposition "reputed," is very uncommon for "ill," it's more common for "well" and "highly." But note that most of those usages are from past centuries!
But much more common than all these is still "he is of good repute."


Also relatively common is the attributive adjective form the ill-reputed John, but John is ill-reputed is definitely "weird".

I have only ever heard 'ill repute' being used, never 'well repute(d)' nor 'highly repute(d)'. Might depend on country/region though.

@paddotk You can check out some of the usages by clicking through from the ngram to Google books results. You'll notice from the ngram itself that they were far more common in the 19th century, and many of the 20th century results are actually modern publications quoting older works, like Shakespeare. I'll add something about that to the answer.
